# SPI Mode 2 (Clock Polarity: 1, Clock Phase: 0) is not working when I am interfacing ADS1293 with ESP32 Wroom 32

Tags: embedded, spi, data-transfer, esp-idf

I have interfaced the ESP-32 Wroom32E (using IDF and APIs) with ADS1293 which is a heart monitoring sensor. I have used simple SPI protocol to read the register values. My SPI protocol is working perfectly fine with all SPI modes- Mode 0,1 and 3 however, **Mode 2 is NOT giving me any values of the register**.

I do not know whether it's hardware problem or am I missing something.

code snippet of configuring device structure:

```
    spi_device_interface_config_t devcfg={
        .clock_speed_hz=10*1000*1000,           //Clock out at 10 MHz
        .mode=0,                                //SPI mode 0: CPOL:-0 and CPHA:-0
        .spics_io_num=PIN_NUM_CS,               //This field is used to specify the GPIO pin that is to be used as CS
        .queue_size=7,                          //We want to be able to queue 7 transactions at a time
    };
```

I have checked all the modes- 0,1,2 and 3. I am receiving the data through all the modes of SPI except mode-2.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your post to make it an actual question, since there is no question. It _might_ be "Why does it not work in mode 2?" But this is only an assumption, please clarify. And while you're at it, please add why you expect that all modes work with a given sensor, which commonly supports only one mode. Oh, and a link to the sensor's data sheet will save all of us the research.